# How can I add an image to the tkinter start page class?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on a simple Tkinter program to store data in excel the only problem that I have is that I am not sure how to add an image to the start page class to display to make the app look better. I would appreciate a little help. The only thing that has worked is to add the image at the end after the app object but I only want to display it on the start page.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import datetime
import tkinter as tk
import xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy
import xlwt
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

style1 = xlwt.XFStyle()
style1.num_format_str = "D-MM-YY"

read_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("test2.xls", formatting_info=True)
read_sheet = read_workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

workbook = copy(read_workbook)
sheet = workbook.get_sheet(0)

sheet.write(0, 0, datetime.now(), style1)
sheet.write(0, 1, "Item")
sheet.write(0, 2, "Size")
sheet.write(0, 3, "Color")
sheet.write(0, 4, "Quantity")

LARGE_FONT = ("Times New Roman", 16)
number = read_sheet.nrows

class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Ordering app")


        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, Chair, Table):
            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        item_label = tk.Label(self, text="Select your item ")
        item_label.grid(column=5, row=0)

        chair_button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Chair",
                                  command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Chair))
        chair_button1.pack()
        chair_button1.grid(column=0, row=3)

        table_button = tk.Button(self, text="Table",
                                 command= lambda: controller.show_frame(Table))

        # table_button.pack()

        table_button.grid(column=10, row=3)

class Chair(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        size_label = tk.Label(self, text="Enter the size")

        size_label.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.size_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.size_entry.grid(column=2, row=0)

        color_label = tk.Label(self, text="Enter the color")
        color_label.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.color_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.color_entry.grid(column=2, row=1)

        quantity_label = tk.Label(self, text="Enter the quantity")
        quantity_label.grid(column=0, row=2)
        self.quantity_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.quantity_entry.grid(column=2, row=2)

        done_button = tk.Button(self, text="Finish the order",
                                command=self.get_chair_data)
        done_button.grid(column=1, row=4)


        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.grid(column=1, row=5)

    def get_chair_data (self):
        global number

        size = self.size_entry.get()
        sheet.write(number, 1, "Chair")
        sheet.write(number, 2, size)

        color = self.color_entry.get()
        sheet.write(number, 3, color)

        quantity = int(self.quantity_entry.get())
        sheet.write(number, 4, quantity)

        number += 1

        workbook.save("test2.xls")


class Table(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


        size_label = tk.Label(self, text="Enter the size")
        size_label.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.size_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.size_entry.grid(column=2, row=0)

        color_label = tk.Label(self, text="Enter the color")
        color_label.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.color_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.color_entry.grid(column=2, row=1)

        quantity_label = tk.Label(self, text="Enter the quantity")
        quantity_label.grid(column=0, row=2)
        self.quantity_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.quantity_entry.grid(column=2, row=2)

        done_button = tk.Button(self, text="Finish the order",
                                command=self.get_table_data)
        done_button.grid(column=1, row=4)

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))

        button2.grid(column=1, row=5)


    def get_table_data(self):
        global number

        size = self.size_entry.get()
        sheet.write(number, 1, "Table")
        sheet.write(number, 2, size)

        color = self.color_entry.get()
        sheet.write(number, 3, color)

        quantity = int(self.quantity_entry.get())
        sheet.write(number, 4, quantity)

        number += 1

        workbook.save("test2.xls")


app = App()
app.geometry("500x500")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I recommend starting by creating a new program with just a single frame, and figure out how to put an image as a background on it (there are answers on this site for how to do it). Once you learn how to do it in that single frame, the knowledge will transfer directly to this program.

Comment: I tried that but I could not figure it out I was hoping to get the answer

Comment: It would help if you showed what you tried.